# Accessing variables in allocated memory

Tags: c, pointers

Lets say I want to allocate memory for 3 integers:

```
int *pn = malloc(3 * sizeof(*pn));
```

Now to assign to them values I do:

```
pn[0] = 5550;
pn[1] = 11;
pn[2] = 70000;
```

To access 2nd value I do:

```
pn[1]
```

But the [n] operator is just a shortcut for *(a+n). Then it would mean that i access first byte after a index. But int is 4 bytes long so shoudn't i do

```
*(a+sizeof(*a)*n)
```

instead? How does it work?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing that says that the `*(a + n)` works in bytes; unless `a` is a byte pointer of course. All pointer arithmetic is in terms of the pointer's type.

Answer (score 12):

No, the compiler takes care of that. There are special rules in pointer arithmetic, and that is one of them.

If you really only want to increment it by one byte, you have to cast the pointer to a pointer to a type which is one byte long (for example `char`).

Comment: Does every C compiler MUST do this (is it something strict, standarized)?

Comment: Yes it does. At least what the C language defines as a byte.

Comment: And what about *(n + 1)? Does it access the second byte or it works same as n[1]?

Comment: It works the same as `n[1]`. As you noted in your post, the `[]` is just some shortcut in this case.

Answer (score 8):

Good question, but C will automatically multiply the offset by the size of the pointed-to type.  In other words, when you access

```
p[n]
```

for a pointer declared as

```
T *p;
```

you will access the address `p + (sizeof(T) * n)` implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, we can use C99 standard to find out what is going on. According to C99 standard:

> 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting
>       Constraints
>       - 1
>       One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to object type’’, the other expression shall
>       have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘type’’.
>       Semantics
>       - 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets **[]** is a subscripted
>       designation of an element of an array object. The definition of the subscript operator **[]**
>       is that **E1[E2]** is identical to **(*((E1)+(E2)))**. Because of the conversion rules that
>       apply to the binary + operator, if **E1** is an array object (equivalently, a pointer to the
>       initial element of an array object) and **E2** is an integer, **E1[E2]** designates the **E2-th**
>       element of **E1** (counting from zero).

And from 6.5.5.8 about conversion rules for `+` operator:

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
>       result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of
>       an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from
>       the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original
>       array elements equals the integer expression. In other words, if the expression P points to
>       the i-th element of an array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and
>       (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and i−n-th elements of
>       the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression P points to the last
>       element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the
>       array object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object,
>       the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object. If both the pointer
>       operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
>       element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>       behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it
>       shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.

Thus, all these notes are about your case and it works exactly as you wrote and you don't need special constructions, dereferencing or anything else (pointers arithmetic do that for you):

```
pn[1] => *((pn)+(1))
```

Or, in terms of byte pointers (to simplify description what is going on) this operation is similar to :

```
pn[1] => *(((char*)pn) + (1*sizeof(*pn)))
```

Moreover you can access this element with `1[pn]` and result will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should not. The rules what is happening when you add a int to a pointer are not obvious. So better not use your intuition, but read language standards about what is happens in such a cases. For example read more about pointer arithmetics [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) (C) or [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_arithmatic.htm) (C++).

Shortly - a non-void pointer are "measured" in units of the type lengths.

Comment: I would be carefull about that page, it says things about C, but much of the code is C++.